# Monitor mysql changes on multiple servers

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, debugging, monitoring

My Situation is as follows:
I have multiple MySQL servers to connect to with ssh and the same table on every server to monitor for changing data.

Is there a way/script/tool to monitor changes in a specific table across different MySQL servers?

I didn't ment a tool to observe mysql itself. I'm just interested in data.
In the best case there is a way to do it without installation on the server. Cause I have to remove it completely when its done.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/

Comment: Have you tried MONyog - https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog. It's a great MySQL monitoring tool and agentless too, which fits your requirement quite well. But it's a commercial tool.